# Change From :Id in URL in Rails 3 Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Boy this seems like a piece of cake, but I can't find it in the [routing bible](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) --

Is there a way to change the default parameter ':id' to something else like ':pid' without using 'match /post/:pid'? I want to avoid using 'match' because it feels particularly brittle.

**Edit** To confirm, this is only a success if i can do:

```
pid = params[:pid]
```

Doing:

```
pid = params[:id]
```

works already, but is wrong code, because it's not an id in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `to_param` method in your model:

```
def to_param
  pid
end
```

Then all of your generated links, etc. will use the `pid` instead of `id`. And in your controller, `params[:id]` will actually give you `pid`, not `id`.

Comment: Same comment as above - I want to use params[:pid] to get the pid, not params[:id].

Comment: Gets the check because you broke the bad news that I have to hard code the route :(

Answer (score 3):

If I got you right check this out:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url

Basically you should override `to_param` method in the model:

```
  def to_param
  pid
end
```

And when you will want to fetch an object, do this in the controller:

```
@object= Object.find_by_pid(params[:id])
```

Good luck!

Comment: It will actually still use `params[:id]`, not `params[:pid]` (unless you define custom routes using `:pid` as the parameter name).

Comment: Right, but this is a smell, because params[:id] has a pid in it, not an id. I want to use params[:pid] to get the pid.